# Can I insert a string into a URL only if the string is not empty?

Tags: angular, string, typescript, url, get

I try to get data from a database. There are optional parts that I can include to make the search more specific.

I have an object like this:

```
{
  title: "wonderland",
  aliases: "",
  ...
}
```

Now I want to create an URL for the GET-Request

```
getResults(obj){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/title=${obj.title}&aliases=${obj.aliases}`)
}
```

Now I want to drop the part `&aliases=${obj.aliases}` because, as you see above, the property aliases is in this case empty. 
If the property title were empty, I would want to drop `title=${obj.title}`.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Better than what you are trying to do

```
let object = {
  title: "wonderland",
  aliases: ""
}

function addOptionalParameters(urlPath) {
  let count = 0;

  for(let param in object){
    if (object[param]) {
      if (count === 0 ) {
        urlPath = `${urlPath}/${param}=${object[param]}`
      } else {
        urlPath = `${urlPath}&${param}=${object[param]}`
      }
      count ++;
    }
  }

  return urlPath;
}

function getResults(obj) {
  let urlPath = `${this.url}`
  urlPath = addOptionalParameters(urlPath)

  return this.http.get(`${urlPath}`)
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of optional strings. Would I have to  use if statements for every single property?

Comment: No, create a function instead. The function should accept input and append based on the status. I will update according.

Comment: @Logik see the updated version. Also, you need to make sure object keys are used as params key else logic won't work

Comment: Hey, thanks. I got the solution. It has the same approach as you are using but the only difference is that I use Object.entries

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
getAliasQuery(aliases) {
    if (aliases) return '&aliases=${aliases}';
    return '';
}

getResults(obj){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/title=${obj.title}${getAliasQuery(obj.aliases)}`)
}
```